# Android AlertDialog item unclicked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog defined this way:

```
final CharSequence[] items = { "Red", "Green", "Blue", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a color");

builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

        // Set items uncheckable

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});

builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

**FIRST QUESTION**

Is it possible to mark some of the items as uncheckable?
Although I'm showing various items I what the user understand that the items exist but some of them are uncheckable.

**SECOND QUESTION**

If there is a way to accomplish my first question, is it possible to put that uncheckable items grayed out?

Thanks,

favolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
(AlertDialog)builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

Here is another way:

```
Button button = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
button.setEnabled(false)
```

See if that works. **Also make sure you this after `builder.create();`** but `before alert.show()`

**EDIT:** For the list items I think you can use [getListView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#getListView%28%29) with that you can access the checkable options, and the use `setEnabled(false)`

Comment: Thanks but I was referring to items on the `CharSequence[]`. For example, set items `Red`, `One` and `Five` to be uncheckabe and grayed out (or some other color)

Comment: I see what you are saying. Take a look at my edit maybe that helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but `ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();` `list.setEnabled(false);` makes the ALL list disabled, not just the desired items at the list. It evens disable the scrolling on the list...

Answer (score 0):

You must choose a specific child item and then disable it:

```
ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
list.getChildAt(item).setEnabled(false);
```